# Why check $_POST['expected_posts']?

Tags: php, validation

I'm reading a book and in chapter about forms the author is checking all expected $_POST values.

Like this:

```
$expected = array('first', 'middle', 'last');
$required = array('first', 'last');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
   if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
       $missing[] = $key;
   } elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {   // <<<-- THIS CHECK
    ${$key} = $temp;
   }
}
```

What is the point of checking for ONLY expected values in $_POST, as I understand the script ONLY gets the data when I explicitly call `$_POST['this_one']` and then work further with this_one specific data.

What harm can the attacker do if he passes me any data with `$_POST['not_expected_value']` - if I don't call it in my script, because I don't expect it? Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: It may not be specifically about malicious `$_POST` Data, the developer might wish to make sure than mandatory fields are entered by the user, then other fields will be used optionally

Comment: How old is this book? This looks like a very bad idea: `${$key} = $temp;` It's basically dynamically creating variables, which will overwrite existing variables. I guess that's why there's the `in_array` check before, but still that's not the right way to handle post data.

Comment: The author it specifically talks about possible attack

Comment: @Zprogrammer, the attack is possible because of poor programming to begin with (dynamically injecting variables, potentially global ones, in the current scope). The solution is to *not* do that to begin with. To access POST variables, simply use $_POST['somename']. If the user post keys you don't expect, you can ignore them in your code, there's no security risk in doing so.

Comment: 2010 unfortunately, I'm will not use this code in my practice, but never read anywhere about cheking not expected values in $_POST, I'm i'm wondering why

Comment: I absolutely agree about the poor code, but my concern is that - do I have to ever check for NOT expected $_POST ( I don't think anyone in his mind is still using globals On )

Comment: Type Checking is invaluable in form validation, which is what that check is doing, but not in a traditional sense.  The author is type checking for extra form variables on the fly If $Temp is empty then move first and last name into it along with the index key else move first last and middle.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is badly coded, passing `'username'` as a key might do some damage. Or how about `'access_level'`? Don't think people don't try this stuff.

Comment: `$_POST['_POST']` would be terrifying as well.  User-controlled input + variable variables = a bad time.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Nope; ["Superglobals cannot be used as variable variables inside functions or class methods."](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: Today I learned.  Still, using user-controlled input to populate variable variables is a terrible idea.